# How to extract those rows in a 2d array whose first element is in a different list?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have this array

```
array([[100,   1],
       [200,   2],
       [300,   3],
       [400,   4],
       [440,   3]])
```

And I have this list or a 1d array `[100,300]`.
I want my operation to output `[1,3]`.
How can I do this in numpy.

I am actually using these numpy arrays within Theano (a machine learning library which speeds up computation using gpu). I will have lots of rows. Numpy arrays allow me to seamlessly use them as Tensor objects in Theano. But if I had to use a dictionary I would have to do that in plain Python, and I am not sure if that will hold up well, once I move on to large data. So I am actually looking for a numpy operation, some trick in indexing or something like that.

Comment: What operation would you like to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [np.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
In [12]: arr
Out[12]: 
array([[100,   1],
       [200,   2],
       [300,   3],
       [400,   4],
       [440,   3]])

In [14]: vals = [100, 300]
In [23]: np.in1d(arr[:,0], vals)
Out[23]: array([ True, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [24]: arr[np.in1d(arr[:,0], vals), 1]
Out[24]: array([1, 3])
```

If you need to call `np.in1d` for many different values of `vals`, then it may pay to prepare a dict as **arshajii** suggests, since after preparing the dict (a `O(n)` operation, where `n = len(arr)`), looking up the values would be a `O(m)` operation, where `m = len(vals)`.

If `n` gets very large however, a dict may require too much memory. In that case you may need to use `np.in1d`.

If the index (key) values are all `ints` and of small magnitude, there is a NumPy indexing trick you could use to get `O(m)` performance without using a dict:

```
In [30]: big = np.full(arr[:,0].max()+1, np.nan)

In [31]: big[arr[:,0]] = arr[:,1]

In [32]: big[vals]
Out[32]: array([ 1.,  3.])
```

Preparing `big` is an `O(n)` operation, but indexing `big[vals]` is `O(m)`. If `arr[:,0].max()` is small and the key values are `ints`, the advantage of using `big` is that it requires less memory than using a `dict`.

---

```
In [33]: %timeit arr[np.in1d(arr[:,0], vals), 1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.5 µs per loop

In [34]: %timeit big[vals]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 µs per loop
```

Compare with arshajii's solution:

```
In [38]: d = dict(arr)
In [40]: %timeit [d[k] for k in vals]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 447 ns per loop
```

So the best method to use depends on the size of `arr` and `vals`, how many times you will be performing this operation, how much memory you have, and if the keys are small `ints`. You'll need to benchmark on data relevant to your use case to make a good decision.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. in1d seems to be exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply convert your array to a dictionary:

```
>>> a = array([[100,   1],
...            [200,   2],
...            [300,   3],
...            [400,   4],
...            [440,   3]])
>>> 
>>> keys = [100, 300]
>>> 
>>> d = dict(a)
>>> 
>>> [d[k] for k in keys]
[1, 3]
```

Comment: I would assume that the rows can become longer than just 2 elements.

Comment: @Midnighter What would the OP want in that case as the final list? I'm not sure we should assume that because the OP's example suggests that the rows will always have 2 elements.

Comment: Yes, I will have only two columns. But I am actually using these numpy arrays within Theano (a machine learning library which speeds up computation using gpu). I will have lots of rows. Numpy arrays allow me to seamlessly use them as Tensor objects in Theano. But if I had to use a dictionary I would have to do that in plain Python, and I am not sure if that will hold up well, once I move on to large data.

So I am actually looking for a numpy operation, some trick in indexing or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that all values to search for are actually present in the search array, you could also use `np.searchsorted`. Seems faster compared to the other suggestions, for large arrays.

```
s = np.sort(A[:,0])
A[np.searchsorted(s, values), 1]
```

If the array to search in is already sorted, you can omit the sort off course and the operation will be even quicker.